# Retrofit's @EncodedPath is deprecated, is there any alternatives?

Tags: android, retrofit

To performance get request in my android app I use retrofit version 1.9.0. It seems that the `@EncodedPath` is now deprecated. Is there any alternatives that can I use?

Comment: Review this [issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1168). This may help you alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the documentation of [`@EncodedPath`](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/parent-1.9.0/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/http/EncodedPath.java#L38):

> Use {@link Path} with {@link Path#encode() encode = false}.

You can use `@Path(value = "whatever", encode = false)`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Discussion](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1168) in same issue.

Path replacements that span multiple path segments aren't going to be supported, `@Path` replacement, whether encoded is set to true or false, will always encode the / character because it replaces inside single path segments.
So use

```
Use {@link Path} with {@link Path#encode() encode = false}
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you are using Retrofit v2.0 you can use the new dynamic @Url